# Heroku missing module

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm trying to deploy a simple node.js server to Heroku, but keep running into this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'morgan'
```

I'm using `morgan` to do some HTTP logging, i have morgan in my `package.json` under the devDependencies (along with many others)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "morgan": "~1.5.0"
}
```

I can do `npm install` locally and start the server without any issues, but when I deploy to Heroku I keep running into that error once it starts the server.

Is there anything I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default Heroku execute `npm install --production` which avoid install devDependencies, quoting literally documentation of Heroku.

> The Heroku node buildpack runs npm install --production, which doesn’t install devDependencies in your package.json file. If you wish to install development dependencies when deploying to Heroku, you should move your build dependencies (such as grunt plugins) from devDependencies to dependencies in package.json.

If you use the Morgan module, you need move it to 'dependencies'.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked that.