# Heroku build fails: Can't find module

Tags: heroku, redux

Heroku Deployment Build is failing. Error:

```
Cannot find module: 'react-redux'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

However:

1. Running npm run build works locally
2. I have react-redux in my package.json file (^7.2.0)

I am using express as my server and react on the client side. React and redux is installed in my client folder. All of the other modules installed and my build was working fine until I installed redux.

Any idea why this module can't be found?

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder while deploying and only keep the dependencies attached in `package.json`! Let it automatically install all the required packages on  it's own.

Comment: "I have react-redux in my package.json"—please [edit] your question and add your `package.json`.

Comment: Hey everyone, I actually figured it out. I had 'react-redux' in my "devDependicies". I moved them to 'dependencies' and that fixed it :) . Silly mistake haha

Thanks everyone for your comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku missing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182433/heroku-missing-module)

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627).

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I had 'react-redux' in the 'devDependicies' section on my package.json file. Moving 'react-redux' to the 'dependencies' fixed the issue. :D